# How do I get the CSRF Token inside JS variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

The response that I'm getting in JMeter vs Browser's Network tab response doesn't match. There's a CSRF token but it's not placed on a hidden input tag it's inside a JS var and is being returned when page is accessed.

I'm using a `Regular Expression Extractor` but I'm not sure if I get the correct CSRF value

So the script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrf_token = "CSRFTokenHere"
```

And my Regular Expression Extractor looks like this:

```
window.csrf_token              = '(.+?)';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like:

```
var csrf_token = "(.+?)"
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Demo]

Useful materials:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)